# Addition function in Windows X86 via inline asm lines in C code

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here:

```
int MachineAdder(int a, int b)
{
    int OUT = 0;        /* Assign a pointer (&OUT) and write initial data (0) */

    __asm ("mov %[dst], %[src]" /* Machine instruction to execute, separated by commas.*/
      : [dst] "=r" (OUT)
      : [src] "r" (a)
    );
    __asm ("add %[dst], %[src]" /* Machine instruction to execute, separated by commas.*/
      : [dst] "=r" (OUT)
      : [src] "r" (b)
    );

    return OUT; /* Return the value a+b */
}
```

In my `main()` function, I call:

```
printf("0+0 = %d\n", MachineAdder(0,0));
printf("0+1 = %d\n", MachineAdder(0,1));
printf("1+0 = %d\n", MachineAdder(1,0));
printf("1+1 = %d\n", MachineAdder(1,1));
printf("2+1 = %d\n", MachineAdder(2,1));
printf("1+2 = %d\n", MachineAdder(1,2));
```

In my output, it reads "0 2 0 2 2 4" (whereas I'd expect "0 1 1 2 3 3").

Thanks! Googling answers was messy because some machine instructions seem to be back to front, while others talk about registers but I don't know which register is which or how to use them.

EDIT: Working solution found. There were two errors: src and dst were the wrong way around, and I had never heard of the "+r" string, used for inout parameters. Here's the fixed version:

```
int MachineAdder(int a, int b)
{
    int OUT = 0;        /* Assign a pointer (&OUT) and write initial data (0) */

    __asm ("mov %[src], %[dst]" /* Machine instruction to execute, separated by commas.*/
      : [dst] "=r" (OUT)
      : [src] "r" (a)
    );
    __asm ("add %[src], %[dst]" /* Machine instruction to execute, separated by commas.*/
      : [dst] "+r" (OUT)
      : [src] "r" (b)
    );

    return OUT; /* Return the value a+b */
}
```

Thanks all!

Comment: In the second one you need to say that dst is both in and out. Also the back-to-front order is an annoying GCC thing.

Comment: Your second block specifies `OUT` as output only but of course it reads the value so you should specify it read-write. Use the `+` constraint. Also if you compile with at&t assembly (the default) you need to swap the operand order. It's fine in intel mode (`-masm=intel`)

Comment: Perhaps you want both those instructions in the same asm statement, so `OUT` is write-only (from the perspective of the compiler).  It's basically pointless to write an asm statement that's just a `mov`; you could have done the same thing with an input matching-constraint like `"0"(a)`.  Also, the comment for `int OUT = 0;` makes little sense; no addresses are involved here.

Comment: Also, if you don't know how to use registers in normal asm, you should learn that first before you try to learn GNU C inline asm.  You have to understand both asm *and* C, and more or less how compilers think, because you need to be able to describe your asm to the compiler accurately as a black box.  Otherwise you get undefined behaviour like this.  If you can't debug it by looking at the compiler-generated asm to try to figure out what it thought you were telling it (e.g. `gcc -S`, or https://godbolt.org/), you're diving in to pretty deep water.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, in the output operands, `=` mark doesn't guarantee that the location has the existing value while `+` mark does.

[Extended Asm (Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC))](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#OutputOperands) says:

> Output constraints must begin with either ‘=’ (a variable overwriting an existing value) or ‘+’ (when reading and writing). When using ‘=’, do not assume the location contains the existing value on entry to the asm, except when the operand is tied to an input